# Granularity of MVC controller action unit tests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

Suppose I have an action that looks something like this:

```
...
var userInfo = authService.SignIn(signInModel.UserName, signInModel.Password);    

if (userInfo == null)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username/password");
    return RedirectToAction(MVC.Home.Index());
}

var userData = new UserData
{
    UserID = userInfo.UserID,
    Name = userInfo.Name,
    Email = userInfo.Email,
    Roles = userInfo.Roles
};

string serializedUserData = textSerializer.Serialize(userData);

formsAuthHelper.CreateAuthCookie(userInfo.UserName, serializedUserData);
...
```

Should I be writing a separate unit test for each of these scenarios:

- Verify that the Serialize method was called once
- Verify that the CreateAuthCookie method was called once

Or can I write a single unit test that verifies both of the above?

Answer (score 0):

I would create one test for each beahviour. One for verifying the call to Serialize and other for the call to CreateAuthCookie.

That way if at some point one of the calls is removed, you will just need to remove the appropriate unit test without needing to edit an existing one.

Also, if you use a naming convention for your tests in the form of

```
void When_Calling_XXXX_With_YYYY_Then_ZZZZZ();
```

The ZZZ part will be more readable

Answer (score 0):

I think this is entirely a personal preference, but I would verify both in a single unit test.

The way I view a test is that given a certain context, some outcome is achieved. Sometimes that means multiple methods or services need to be called to achieve that outcome. Setting the auth cookie only makes sense in light of Serialize() succeeding, and likewise the only reason to call Serialize() is to create the auth token. They *can't* run independent of each other, so the unit tests shouldn't either. *Given a valid username and password, a user is signed in*. In this case it means that you validated the user's password, and created a token with the requisite data.

Also I think in practical terms, doing all the setup work just for "purity" of tests is a waste of time. Other answer's mention the ease of updating tests if you refactor this action in the future. In my experience, if you do rewrite it, it's going to be such a substantial change that you're going to have to redo the tests anyway.

A bit offtopic, but it's why I love the [Machine.specifications](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications) test framework, because you're doing a single setup, but the test runner treats each of your verifies as separate tests.

```
public class when_calling_login_with_a_valid_username_and_password
{
    Because of = () => controller.Login(...);

    It should_call_serialize = () => textSerializer.Serialize().MustHaveBeenCalled();
    It should_set_the_auth_token = () => formsAuthHelper.CreateAuthCookie().MustHaveBeenCalled()
}
```